# How to write the right appsettings.json file for custom Enricher within argument

Tags: c#, appsettings, serilog

I have a custom Enricher: `CorrelationIdsEnricher` in order to write the `CorrelationId` and `RequestId` to log, and its constructor has an argument: `ICorrelationContextProvider` for passing the correlation context provider.

In my project, i config the serilog by reading the `appsettings.json` config file. And here's the config file:

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Common.Logging", "Common.Correlation" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] [{SourceContext}] [{EventId}] [{RequestId} {CorrelationId}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
          "theme": "Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Themes.AnsiConsoleTheme::Code, Serilog.Sinks.Console"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [
      "FromLogContext",
      {
        "Name": "WithCorrelationIds",
        "Args": {
          "provider": "Correlation.ServerContextProvider::Default, Common.Correlation"
        }
      }
    ],
  }
}
```

However it can not set the `CorrelationIdsEnricher` correctly.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Could you please add the code for `WithCorrelationIds` method to your question?

Comment: You are right. I just forgot to write the `WithCorrelationIds` extension method

Comment: ..but how the configuration reader knows which class's method is the WithCorrelationIds method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that i forgot to add the `WithCorrelationIds` extension method. I thought implementing the `CorrelationIdsEnricher` is enough at first.

After looking into the source code [ConfigurationReader.cs](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Settings.Configuration/Settings/Configuration/ConfigurationReader.cs) of `serilog-settings-configuration`, i found that i forget to implement extensions `WithCorrelationIds`.

That's to say, in order to support initializing serilog from configuration for our custom `Enricher` and `Sink`, we need to not only create the `Enricher` and `Sink` class but also implement their `LoggerSinkConfiguration` extensions.

Attached the `CorrelationIdsEnricher` implementation:

```
using Common.Correlation;
using Serilog.Core;
using Serilog.Events;

namespace Common.Logging.Enrichers
{
    public class CorrelationIdsEnricher : ILogEventEnricher
    {
        private readonly ICorrelationContextProvider _provider;

        public CorrelationIdsEnricher(ICorrelationContextProvider provider)
        {
            _provider = provider;
        }

        public void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory propertyFactory)
        {
            var (requestId, correlationId) = GetIds();
            logEvent.AddPropertyIfAbsent(
                propertyFactory.CreateProperty("RequestId", requestId, false));
            logEvent.AddPropertyIfAbsent(
                propertyFactory.CreateProperty("CorrelationId", correlationId, false));
        }

        private (string requestId, string correlationId) GetIds()
        {
            var ctx = _provider.Context;
            return (ctx?.RequestId ?? string.Empty, ctx?.CorrelationId ?? string.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

And `LoggerEnrichmentConfiguration` Extensions:

```
public static LoggerConfiguration WithCorrelationIds(
    this LoggerEnrichmentConfiguration enrichmentConfiguration,
    ICorrelationContextProvider provider)
{
    return enrichmentConfiguration.With(new CorrelationIdsEnricher(provider));
}
```

And here's a mocked correlation provider:

```
public class CorrelationContextProvider : ICorrelationContextProvider
{
    public static ICorrelationContextProvider Default { get; } = new CorrelationContextProvider();
    public ICorrelationContext Context => new CorrelationContext();
}
```